# How to change PPTP VPN client's port number?

Tags: vpn

I saw this post: [Change PPTP control connection's TCP port number](https://superuser.com/questions/381362/change-pptp-control-connections-tcp-port-number) and I successfully did it on my PC.

But how do I change Android's PPTP VPN client's port number? My Android phone is rooted and I installed a terminal emulator so I can run Linux commands.

Which commands do I need to run?

Answer (score 0):

use
serveripaddress:portnumber

example
111.200.123.55:1755

this way you are over ruling the default 1723 pptp port 
but make sure the server is listening to the new port

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 0):

It's not about your device.
You must connect to the same exact port the VPN server is connected to.